# A better approach to storing data in c++ with this format

Tags: c++, python-3.3, python-2.6

So I come from Python and still very new with c++. I would like to do a similar dictionary structure like this in c++

dataDict = { 1:('value 1', 'value 2',...), 2:('value 1', 'value 2',...) }

Usage: I plan on accesing them using their keys and edit/update their values if necessary. Does using a map possible or a multidimensional array?

Comment: Use a map, and a pair from STL

Comment: The most direct equivalent data structure in C++ land would probably be `std::unordered_multimap<int,string>` , because I think in python all maps are hash-maps.

Comment: but if you know that the integer values are sequential and starting at 0 you're probably better off with `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`

Comment: Hi PeterT forgot to mention my keys are auto generated. I'll have a look at vector, thanks

Comment: peterT in your unordered multimap, I'm assuming your string part takes a single long string? What i need is a list of string. More like a list within a dictionary?

Comment: @eakdev a multimap is a map that can map multiple values to one key

Comment: peterT thank you, I should read more about that :)

Comment: After reading a bit about map and multimap,  i think its better i use map like this map<int,  vector<string>> data; since i want the key values to be unique. Would this suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a

```
std::map<std::string, T>
```

where T is the type of the data you want to store in the dictionary

Comment: Hi Jens, if I understand correctly your map is like a list of strings, what im aiming for isa a key:value pair where the value is a list/array of strings

Comment: Something like this: `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >`.